# jQuery ajax defined actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I'm loading some content through ajax it returns an jQuery .click event and some elements. But when the ajax content is loaded a couple of times and I click the the button that is bound to the .click event, the action is executed a couple of times.

For example the ajax content is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#click').click(function() { alert('test') });
</script>
<input type="button" id="click" value="click here">
```

If this is refreshed 5 times and I click the button I will get 5 alert boxes.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the unbind function just before the click, something like this:

$('#click').unbind('click').click(function() { alert('test') });

That should let only one function associated with the click

Comment: Thank you willvv, that did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery one method unbinds the handler after it is invoked:

```
$('#click').one("click",function() { alert('test') });
```

More info:
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one